# Include preferences from a topic

Tags: twiki, foswiki

How to include preferences from another topic in **Foswiki 1.1.9**? This approach doesn't work for me:

*Sandbox.MyPreferences*

```
   * Set FOO = 1
```

*Sandbox.UseFoo*

```
%INCLUDE{"Sandbox.MyPreferences"}%
Value for FOO is %FOO%
```

Output of *Sandbox.UseFoo*

```
Value for FOO is %FOO%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility would be to use SpreadSheet variables to accomplish something similar.  Unlike Foswiki Preferences, spreadsheet variables can be set in an included topic and then used in the including topic.  I've seen this used to centralize a number of calculations into a separate include topic which can then be referenced in a number of topics.

I wrote up an example from a past life.  See http://foswiki.org/Support/BestPracticeTip33

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. `* Set` lists can't be `%INCLUDed`. However the upcoming Foswiki-1.2.0 will have a macro-equivalent to * Set which in fact will
allow you to `%INCLUDE` them as you described. See http://foswiki.org/Development/SettingAndGettingVariablesUsingMacros.